# dart js-interop FunctionProxy callback relationship to js.context

Tags: callback, dart

I have a Dart js-interop callback that in turn takes a javascript callback as an argument.  The dart callback implementation looks like this:

```dart
void callBackToDartCode(String query, js.FunctionProxy completionCallback) {
  js.context.completionCallback = completionCallback;
  doSomethingAscyn(query).then(
    (result) {
       // hand the query result back to the javascript code
       js.context.completionCallback(js.map(result));
  });
```

This works. The key to making this work is to save the FunctionProxy in the js.context so that it is available when it comes time to execute it in the async "then" method. This line of code is important:

```dart
js.context.completionCallback = completionCallback;
```

If that's not done then the completeCallback is not retained and hence cannot be called when the async operation completes.

I have not seen examples like this and I am not sure I have really done this properly.

It raises questions:

1. How do I disassociate "completeCallback" from js.context after I've called it?  Does it remain associated with js.context forever?
2. It appears there will be conflicting use of the name "completionCallback" within js.context if multiple async operations are in progress at the same time. That strikes me as a common problem. Does js-interop have a way to deal with that or is it my job to manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *js-interop* all proxies are scoped to prevent memory leaks. This means that `Proxy` will lost its JS object reference at the end of its associated scope. If `scoped((){})` function is not use explicitely a lazy scope is initialized the first time an interop operation is done and the scope is automatically closed at the end of the current event loop. If you want to make a `Proxy` to live longer than its associated scope, you have to retain it. This can be done with `js.retain(proxy)`. Once your proxy is no longer needed, you can release it with `js.release(proxy)`.

Thus your code should be :

```dart
void callBackToDartCode(String query, js.FunctionProxy completionCallback) {
  js.retain(completionCallback);
  doSomethingAscyn(query).then(
    (result) {
       // hand the query result back to the javascript code
       completionCallback(js.map(result));
       // completionCallback is no longer used
       js.release(completionCallback);
  });
}
```

About your question about *disassociate "completeCallback" from js.context* you could have done it with `js.deleteProperty(js.context, "completeCallback")`

Comment: I actually started out using js.retain(completionCallback) but that call generates an "Illegal type: funcref" exception. It was that that caused me to try the code I posted. (I missed deleteProperty in the docs - obvious. thanks)

Comment: It seems that retaining FunctionProxy is not supported for now. Please [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop/issues/new).